# Logging anonymous function in the chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have some code like this:

```
obj.addEventListener('event', function(eventType) {
});
```

When I debug this in the chrome web deveoper Profiler, I always see it as anonymous function, but I would rather like to see it as the contents of eventType.

Is it possible to rename or wrap this somehow, preferable in an efficent way, without the need of a separate function for each eventType?

Or maybe is it possible to timestamp the Profiler like it's possible in Timeline so that I can make a distinction between the different eventTypes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the function name to depend on its arguments, "without the need of a separate function for each eventType"?
I think that really is impossible.
Apparently a function keeps the name assigned to it at creation.

Try the following:

```
var aaa = function()
{
    debugger;
};
var bbb = aaa;
delete aaa;
(function(){ var ccc = bbb; ccc(); })();
```

When I run the above code, I see "aaa" in the debugger, and I doubt it'll be different in other parts of the dev tools.

I though maybe one could tamper with `arguments.callee`:

```
var aaa = function()
{
    console.log(arguments.callee.name);
    arguments.callee.name = 'bbb';
    console.log(arguments.callee.name);
    debugger;
};
(function()
{
    var ccc = aaa;
    console.log(ccc.name);
    ccc.name = 'ccc';
    console.log(ccc.name);
    ccc();
})();
```

But that logged four times nothing at all to the console, and it's exactly the same with `arguments.callee.prototype.constructor.name`.
Only logging `arguments.callee.prototype` logs `aaa {}`, which suggests that the name is bound internally somehow.

So without creating additional functions, this is hardly possible.
You could use *one* name for the function name, as suggested in [JLRishe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30121937/2302862).

Other than that, you have no choice but to create some functions at runtime.
The not make them show up as different functions in the profiler however, you should probably have a global object on which you assign created functions so you can reuse them.

I suggest the following setup:

Make the actual handler function global, like:

```
function actualEventHandler(eventType) { /* ... */ }
```

Have a global object to store your on-the-fly created functions to:

```
var handlerFunctions = {};
```

And then in your assigned event handler function, check if a function for the current event type already exists and create a function with a name based on that type otherwise:

```
obj.addEventListener('event', function(eventType)
{
    if(handlerFunctions[eventType] === undefined)
    {
        var ev = {};
        ev[eventType] = function(evType)
        {
            actualEventHandler(evType);
        }
        handlerFunctions[eventType] = ev[eventType];
    }
    handlerFunctions[eventType](eventType);
});
```

Since you cannot create a variable with a name from a string, I'm using a temporary object `ev` here, so the function name will be `ev.<whatever>`. If you do not want any prefix at all, you have to use `eval()`.

*Edit:* It seems that in newer versions of Chrome, the trick with a temporary object no longer works, as Chrome now simply displays `ev.(anonymous function)`. You can still do it with `eval` though, **provided that `eventType` is a valid function name**:

```
obj.addEventListener('event', function(eventType)
{
    if(handlerFunctions[eventType] === undefined)
    {
        var fn = null;
        eval('fn = function ev_' + eventType + '(evType){ actualEventHandler(evType); };');
        handlerFunctions[eventType] = fn;
    }
    handlerFunctions[eventType](eventType);
});
```

Then your function will show up in the stack trace prefixed by `ev_`.

I don't know how well this will be reflected in the profiler, and there will still be an anonymous function around all of them (the one passed to `addEventListener` - you could give it a name, but I'm not sure that would really help) and a call to `actualEventHandler` inside, but it should actually show the different functions for all event types.

Comment: Thanks! Now with fat arrow functions it's getting a bit more complicated to debug large applications, because they can't be named.

Comment: I tried the trick with a temporary object, but got `ev.(anonymous function)` in the stack, so that didn't help.

Comment: @Marius Updated my answer, looks like `eval` is your only option now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Named Function Expression to give your function a name that will be shown in the profiler instead of "(anonymous function)":

```
obj.addEventListener('event', function myHandler(eventType) {
});
```

In the above case, the handler would be shown in the profiler as "myHandler".

I think you need to clarify what you mean by "rename or wrap this somehow, preferable in an efficent way, without the need of a separate function for each eventType". From your example, it looks like you're using a separate function for each event type.